# How to make every integer out of $5k + 8q$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Expression given: $N = 5k + 8q$  ($k$ , $q$   integer).  Prove that we can make any integer from this expression.

For example: $0= 5\cdot0+8\cdot0$; $5 = 5\cdot1+8\cdot0$; $3 = 8\cdot1 +5 \cdot(-1)$.

#### Progress

I google and then knowing it is Coin Problem, thanks. Due to bad english, i can't write too much...

Comment: $5 \cdot 5 + 8 \cdot (-3) = 1$

Comment: right, but how to prove this

Comment: First, you need to be precise about what you are trying to prove. "Prove that for all integers $N$, there exist integers $k,q$ such that $N = 5k + 8q$"

Comment: The first line of the proof will be: "Let N be an arbitrary integer. Then choose $k = \cdots$"

Comment: I google and then knowing it is Coin Problem, thanks. Due to bad english, i can't write too much, sr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows from Bezout's Lemma. It states that for given integers $a,b$ the equation:

$$ax + by = d$$

has integer solutions for $x$ and $y$ if and only if $d$ is a multiple of $gcd(a,b)$

Our equation has form:

$$5x + 8y = d$$

Because $(5,8) = 1$ and $1$ is a factor of every number, that implies that this equation has solution for every $d$

Answer (score 1):

Guess I'll go ahead and round out the lesson here.

Let $N$ be any integer. Then choose $k=5N, q = -3N$.

Hence, $$N = 5 \cdot (5N) + 8 \cdot (-3N)$$

Comment: i.e. scale the Bezout identity $\,\large  1 = 5(5)+8(-3)\ $ by $\large \,N\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

All the integer solutions to $5k+8q = N$ are given by
$$k = 5N + 8\ell \text{ and } q = -3N - 5\ell$$
where $\ell \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Can you make any integer N?